# Pythonanywhere save the image files on the one step parent directory rather than correct directory. *development server goes good way)

Tags: image, file, path, pythonanywhere

I have made custom field to save image and thumnail. Thumnail should be saved at '/.../.../targetimage/thumbnails/' folder and full sized images should be at '.../.../targetimage/  'folder.

When I run the customfield file at local development server, the images go into correct directory. But in the pythonanywhere, original and thumbnail images go into same directory.
I can not understand why the Pythonanywhere acts in different way.

fields.py

```
def _add_path_to_thumb(s):
    print('this is path',s)
    fname_list=[]
    parts = s.split(".")
    print('this is parts',parts)
    pathparts=parts[0].split("\\")
    print('this is pathparts', pathparts)
    fname_list.append(pathparts[-1])
    fname_list.append('-thumb')
    fname_list.append('.jpg')
    fname ="".join(fname_list)
    del pathparts[-1]
    pathparts.extend(['thumbnails\\'])
    print('this is pathparts final', pathparts)
    path_prop = "\\".join(pathparts)
    print('this is pathparts final prop', path_prop)
    MEDIA_ROOT_THUMB = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'target_image/thumbnails/')
    print('this is media_root_thumb', MEDIA_ROOT_THUMB)
    fullopathusingos = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT_THUMB,fname)
    print('this is full path using os ',fullopathusingos )

    fullpath = path_prop+fname
    return fullopathusingos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're switching between using \ and / as path separators. It will behave one way on Windows and another way on PythonAnywhere. I suspect the main cause of the problem is splitting on \ because, on PythonAnywhere, you will not get a path where splitting on \ breaks it into directory parts.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was caused by split function. I removed that and used os.path module entirely. I realized the problem of OS caused this confusion. The problem was completely solved with the following code. `def _add_path_to_thumb(s):
    path_list=os.path.split(s)
    fpath = os.path.dirname(s)
    fname = path_list[1]
    fname_s_ext = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
    thumb_fname = fname_s_ext + '-thumb.jpg'
    fpath_for_thumbnails= os.path.join(fpath,'thumbnails')
    fullpath = os.path.join(fpath_for_thumbnails, thumb_fname)
    
    
    return fullpath`